# Deleteing "?" from url using GET method

Tags: url, get

I'm pretty new to php, I'm using `$_GET` method to pass team ID. I have the page or url like this `mywebsite.com/team.php?team=7` but I want this `mywebsite.com/team/7`.

I want it like facebook where you have e.g. `facebook.com/groups/650076305160396/` or your profile `facebook.com/yourname/`

Is it something different or am I able to do it with `$_GET` method too ?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, entirely possible, just extract the values you want from the querystring

Answer (score 0):

You need .htaccess to do this

Use this rule

`RewriteRule ^team/([0-9]+)/?$ team.php?team=$1 [L]`

It will simply rewrite your `team/4455/` to `team.php?team=4455`

So you can use `$_GET` in php script to get the value of team